# Link Phone Number in App to Dialer (Android)

Tags: android, hyperlink, phone-call

How do you link a phone number to the the dialer on an Android App?

I have tried the

```
android:phoneNumber="true"
```

in the xml for the textView, but that did not work.

I want it so that the person touches the number and their phone's dialer opens up and they can push call and call the company I am developing this app for

Answer (score 2):

add `android:autoLink="phone"` in xml

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Linkify class:

[Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)